# Why don't B, C, Si, have ionic forms?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry

Also, why can some elements such as $\ce{Fe}$ have different ionic forms such as $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$? What determines each form?

Comment: Although this is not an explanation, do you know about the octet rule, ionisation energies, etc? We do btw see carbocations, but they aren't very stable.

Answer (score 2):

Boron: borates, borides.  $\ce{MgB2}$ is the highest temperature BCS superconductor by a large margin.

Carbon: carbonates, carbides, hexacoordinate carbon in complexes, organolithiums, Grignard reagents, carbenium ions ($\ce{Ph3C+}$).  $\ce{Al4C3}$ hydrolyzes to methane.

Silicon: silicates, aluminosilicates, silicides.  Cook up silica gel in ethylene glycol plus potassium hydroxide (*NOT* in glass) to get pentacoordinate siliconate,

http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/WO1994020507A1/imgf000014_0001.png

You asked the second half in the Physics Stack.